# Shopify: using our own checkout/billing system

Tags: shopify

I am working with this company that decided to build its eCommerce store based on Shopify but we are stuck at integrating our own billing system / checkout / credit card processor with Shopify. This is basically what we would like to do:

1 - Have customers buy the product on Shopify

2 - redirect customers to Cart on Shopify

3 - Once the customer checks out, we would like to redirect them to our own checkout page that has our own payment system with all the required Json requests along their customer, orders, etc. data

4 - Process the order along the payments and then communicate back with Shopify that the request has been submitted and the order is either fulfilled, canceled, refunded, etc.

In a nutshell, we would like to host our own private billing system and we cannot get a clear grasp to how this could be done? We would like to test this first but the API is not helping much!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you read the latest terms of service with Shopify, you might discover that your business plan is a bust. You won't be using your own checkout. But hey, if you figure you can, have fun!

Edit: If you intercept the Checkout button, at the Cart, you could redirect to your payment gateway. You will scare off people, and perhaps convert way way less, but it will work. When you redirect to your own Gateway, you finish up taking their money and then you start a job to fix things in Shopify. In Shopify you create a Draft order with all the same details, including the financials, and with that, you can have Shopify analytics too. If you convert that Draft Order to a real order, you could probably even do real fulfillments.

So yes... you can do it... but it will never be smooth, it will always be a hack job.

Comment: Shopify Plus is just a contract, it does not change Shopify itself. If your payment gateway is not currently supported in Shopify, there is a reason. If it CAN be supported, ask them to support it. If it cannot be supported in Shopify, then maybe Shopify won't work for you.

Comment: When you subscribe to Shopify, you tell them what gateway to use. You select from a list. If yours is not in the list, ask your Shopify rep to tell you why...

Comment: So it is a chicken and egg problem. If you have your own payment gateway, then why don't you have your own e-commerce system? You should not be using a hosted service like Shopify, you should be hosting your own Shopify-like ecommerce platform as it were. There are plenty to choose from.

Comment: I would run away screaming from this... seems this project has no chance of success.

Comment: Funny eh.. someone forgot to read the fine print. A billion dollars is no substitute for reading the TOS before starting off a project. Besides, they have really lost nothing... just deploy Spree or Magento or any other free open source system and you're done!